# spring security plugin grails 3 quick start artifacts

Tags: grails, spring-security

Spring Security in Grails 3 sets up a login page view and controller after following the quick start guide.
https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#s2-quickstart

There should be auth.gsp, loginController.groovy created somewhere automatically. They are not visible in the app workspace. Where are they?

Answer (score 0):

They're in the plugin, in both the 2.x and 3.x plugins. To override any of them, create a file with the same name and put it in the same relative location in your app and Grails will use yours instead.